# How to set up VPN over http using freelan (or any other free alternative)?

Tags: networking, vpn

Scenario: I've a windows machine on office network which I need to VPN from a home windows machine. It must be a VPN (not merely a remote session). I have full admin rights for both machines. I don't have any control over office network. Both, home and office networks have static public ip address. And of course, I have full control over home network. Office network only allows http traffic ( I proved using trial versions of paid software that as long as VPN is over http, it works fine)

Is it possible to use freelan (freelan.org) to VPN to home computer over http? I'd like to setup home machine as server and client and set up freelan on office machine to talk to my static ip over http (port 80).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing I could see on the Freelan site shows it will work over tcp port 80.  If support for this is not built into the client, it won't work.

You may want to look at OpenVPN which can at least speak on TCP (and apparently also works over proxies with CONNECT support) - so if port 80 is not intercepted you may be able to do it.   Note that if its an option you might be better off using OpenVPN over port 443 (https) as its generally intercepted less, and less likely to be proxied and stuffed up.

Comment: Also see https://serverfault.com/questions/163768/vpn-through-only-http

Comment: OpenVPN only allows two free concurrent connections but it solved the problem.